# Searching for someones name and information in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, singly-linked-list

For this program I'm using a single linked list to have people input their animals information. I am having trouble hashing that linked list to that I can look up any animals name and have their owners last name print as well. When I input information and try to search for an animals name, it does print the animals name correctly but it prints out the last name of the very last owner I input and not of the owner that corresponds to that specific animal.

How can i fix my search function, this is what I have so far...

my header file (Vet.h)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int const MAX_NUMBER_OF_PATIENTS = 100;
int const TABLE_SIZE = 31;

enum Pet_Type
{
Dog,
Cat, 
Bird,
Reptile,
Other
};

class LIST
{
private:
struct Node
{
    char      owners_last_name[30];
    char      pet_name[20];
    char      animals_color[12];
    char      d_o_b[11];
    Pet_Type  pet_type;
    Node      *next;
}; Node *head;

public:
LIST() 
{ 
    head = NULL; 
}
Pet_Type getPetType();
void appendNode();
void Menu();
void Read(Node *);
void Search();
void Display();
void Clear();
void Quit();
};
```

my cpp file (Veterinary.cpp)

```
#include "Vet.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
LIST P;
char        choice = ' ';
int         terminate = 0;
int         counter = 0;
string      name = "NULL";

while( counter != 100 )
{
    P.Menu();
    cin >> choice;
    switch ( choice )
    {
    case 'E' : case 'e':
        if( counter <= MAX_NUMBER_OF_PATIENTS )
        {
            P.appendNode();
            counter++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your database is full\n";
            break;
        }

    case 'S' : case 's':
        P.Search();
        break;

    case 'D' : case 'd':
        P.Display();
        break;

    case 'C' : case 'c':
        P.Clear();
        break;

    case 'Q' : case 'q':
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Number of entries in your database: " << counter << endl << endl;
        P.Quit();
        return 0;
        break;

    }
}
return 0;
}

void LIST::appendNode()
{
Node *newNode, *nodeptr;                

newNode = new Node;                     
Read( newNode );                    
newNode->next = NULL;               

if( !head )                             
{
    head = newNode;                     
}
else
{
    nodeptr = head;                     

    while( nodeptr->next )              
    {
        nodeptr = nodeptr->next;
    }
    nodeptr->next = newNode;
}
}


void LIST::Read( LIST::Node *newNode )
{
cout << "\nPlease enter your pets information.\n";
cout << "Your pets name: ";
cin >> newNode->pet_name;

cout << "Your last name: ";
cin >> newNode->owners_last_name;

newNode->pet_type = LIST::getPetType();

cout << "Your animals date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY): ";
cin >> newNode->d_o_b;

cout << "Your animals color of animal: ";
cin >> newNode->animals_color;
cout << endl;
}

void LIST::Display()
{
Node *nodeptr;
nodeptr = head;
while( nodeptr )
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Pets name: " << nodeptr->pet_name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Owners last name: " << nodeptr->owners_last_name << endl;

    switch ( nodeptr->pet_type )
    {
    case 0:
        cout << "Animal type: Dog\n";
        break;

    case 1:
        cout << "Animal type: Cat\n";
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Animal type: Bird\n";
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Animal type: Reptile\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Animal type: Other\n";
        break;
    }

    cout << "Pets date of birth: " << nodeptr->d_o_b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Pets color: " << nodeptr->animals_color;
    cout << endl << endl;
    nodeptr = nodeptr->next;
}
}

void LIST::Menu()
{
cout << "(E)nter data to database\n";
cout << "(S)earch the database\n";
cout << "(D)isplay data in database\n";
cout << "(C)lear data in database\n";
cout << "(Q)uit the program\n\n";
cout << "What would you like to do? \n";
cout << "Enter a letter: ";
}

Pet_Type LIST::getPetType()
{
int animal_choice;

cout << "What type of animal do you have?\n";
cout << "1) Dog\n";
cout << "2) Cat\n";
cout << "3) Bird\n";
cout << "4) Reptile\n";
cout << "5) Other\n";
cout << "Select a number: ";

cin >> animal_choice;

switch ( animal_choice )
{
case 1:
return Dog;

case 2:
return Cat;

case 3:
return Bird;

case 4:
return Reptile;

default:
return Other;
}
}

void LIST::Clear()
{
cout << "\nDatabase cleared! \n\n";
head = NULL;
}

void LIST::Search()
{
Node *nodeptr;
nodeptr = head;
cout << "Enter the name of the pet you want to search: ";
cin >> nodeptr->pet_name;
cout << endl;
cout << "Pets name: " << nodeptr->pet_name;
cout << endl;
cout << "Owners last name: " << nodeptr->owners_last_name << endl;
}

void LIST::Quit()
{
system( "pause" );
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use `std::map<person_name, animal_name>`.  Don't implement your own linked list; use existing ones.

Comment: Also, remove the `char` arrays and replace with `std::string`.  You really don't want to mess with field overflows.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is giving you issues?

Comment: Okay, i will make those changes. The thing i'm having issues with is printing the last name of the owner that corresponds with the animal name I search for. It does run but it does not print what i want it to print

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for you to use a debugger.  Linked lists are very difficult to debug visually (through code walkthrough).  Much easier to set a breakpoint and examine the variables in use.